# How to write select query which matches data from a static array?

Tags: mysql, clickhouse

I have an array of strings for example
["1234", "3432", "3423", "3442"]

I want to select all records of a table whose ID matches values from this static array.

Please help me with the query.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Whose type is ID in the table? Integer or some kind of string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```sql
SELECT number AS id
FROM numbers(5000)
WHERE id IN 
(
    WITH
        ['1234', '3432', '3423', '3442'] AS ids,
        arrayMap(x -> toInt32(x), ids) AS number_ids
    SELECT arrayJoin(number_ids)
)

/*
┌───id─┐
│ 1234 │
│ 3423 │
│ 3432 │
│ 3442 │
└──────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```sql
Select "1234" union select  "3432" union select  "3423" union select "3442";
```